# Show button in the actionbar when a fragment is displayed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer and I want to show a button in the actionbar only when a precise Fragment is show. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(YourFragment.this.isVisible) { //Fragment is shown
    myBtn.setVisible(true);  //show button
    invalidateOptionsMenu();  //refresh actionbar
}
else{
    // Fragment is not shown
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basically as in an activity. In your fragment:

- In `OnCreate` call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`
- Inflate your menu in `OnCreateOptionsMenu`
- The system calls `onOptionsItemSelected` when an item is selected

See the note on the [Fragment Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionEvents) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this Simple steps and make a try.

1. Create a function in activity that makes that particular button
   visible or hidden.
2. Goto that child fragment from where you want to show menu button on
   actionbar and call function created in step 1 statically.
3. This step is not important but if your desired fragment is in
   viewPager or is created but not on screen. Because in viewPager it
   loads 3 Fragments at a time current one ,previous and next fragment.
   So in this case , override onMenuVisible() or onUserVisible() and
   call function on visibility true using if condition.

Answer (score 0):

In your desired `Fragment` just `override` the following method,

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
}
```

`inflate` the menu using `MenuInflater` and get the menu item as follows,

```
MenuItem yourMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.your_menu_name);
yourMenuItem.setVisible(true);
```

by default in your `menu` and in your menu item `xml` make that `menuitem visiblity` as `false`